# Refresh all icons in desktop and taskbar

Tags: vbscript

I need to refresh the desktop and taskbar icons programmatically using a batch file or VBScript.

I found this vbs that hits the usual refresh key, <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
```

but that obviously doens't refresh the icons I mentioned.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please do not link downloadable `.zip` files.  Explain what you want in the question itself.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Perhaps there is a different solution based on what your desired outcome is?

Answer (score 1):

Try to refresh **Explorer.exe** by killing and running it like this way :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ProcessName : ProcessName = "Explorer.exe"
Refresh(ProcessName)
'*********************************************************************
Sub Refresh(ProcessName)
Kill(ProcessName)
RunIt(ProcessName)
End Sub
'*********************************************************************
Sub Kill(ProcessName)
Dim Ws : Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim Command : Command = "Taskkill /F /IM "& ProcessName &""
Dim Result : Result = Ws.Run(Command,0,True)
End Sub
'*********************************************************************
Sub RunIt(ProcessName)
Dim Ws : Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim Result : Result = Ws.Run(ProcessName,1,False)
End Sub
'*********************************************************************
```